# Adjust to dynamic contentwidth with custom jquery scroll bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollbar, jscrollpane

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hermansen/Ex4G8/11)

I have to display some data in a fixed div. It will usually show all the data in 1 column, but i need it to slide out so i can display the data in several columns (just stacked next to each other displayed as inline-block).

Using the ordinary scrollbar everything works great ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hermansen/Ex4G8/10)).

But when I set up a new scrollbar I can't get it to change the contentwidth, I've tried changing the width of ".jspContainer" while I change width of the scrollbar. I've also tried fiddeling with the api, but I can't get it to work as intended (not sure i grasp the internals of the functions)

Is there a way to solve my problem in JScrollpane or is there another plugin that can help me out?

Html

```
<body>
<button id="animate">Animate</button>
<button id="reinit">reinit with new width</button>
<button id="destroy">Remove JScrollpane</button>
<div id="scroller">
    <div id="a1" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a2" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a3" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a4" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a5" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a6" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a7" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a8" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a9" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a10" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a11" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a12" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a13" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a14" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a15" class="content">hello</div>
    <div id="a16" class="content">hello</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Jquery

```
var scroller = $("#scroller").jScrollPane().data('jsp');
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#destroy").click(function () {
    scroller.destroy();
});
});

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#reinit").click(function () {
    scroller.reinitialise(contentWidth=450);
});
});

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#scroller").jScrollPane();
});


var windowsize = $(window).width();
$(document).ready(function () {
windowsize = (windowsize - 200) / 225;
i = Math.floor(windowsize);
flwidth = "200"
switch (i) {
    case 0:
        flwidth = "225";
        break;
    case 1:
        flwidth = "450";
        break;
    case 2:
        flwidth = "450";
        break;
    case 3:
        flwidth = "647";
        break;
    case 4:
        flwidth = "647";
        break;
        /* and so on */
};
$("#animate").click(function () {
    $("#scroller").animate({
        width: flwidth
    }, 400);
});
```

CSS:

```
#scroller {
right:50px;
position:fixed;
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
height:600px;
/* in reality height is 100% */
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
width:225px;
}

#destroy
{
float:right;
margin-right:50px;
}

.content {
height:75px;
padding:1px;
padding-left:6px;
width:200px;
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
background:rgba(102, 139, 195, 0.2);
}
#a1, #a3, #a5, #a7, #a9, #a11, #a13, #a15 {
background:rgba(102, 139, 195, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ex4G8/14/) using [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar/).

This example is based on your second jsFiddle with native scrollbars. It uses 100% height as you mentioned in CSS. Resize output window to see scrollbar behavior. To make example simplier I've used `position:absolute`. To use `position:fixed`, wrap your scrollable container into another div with fixed position. Also, I've applied CSS styles not to ID, but to classes - it's required by the scrollbar plugin to apply parent CSS to scrollbar wrapper too.